# jQuery: hiding pictures on page load

Tags: jquery, html, css, hide

I need to hide pictures when my internet page is loaded, and make them appear later on (they are triggers for other divs appearing/disappearing). The reason is that i don't want them to be clickable until my .animate() function actually makes them appear for real..
So anyways, I tried a simple...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#img1").hide();
    $("#img2").hide();
});
```

...with the HTML...

```
<img id="img1" src="./images/img1.png" alt="image 1" />
<img id="img2" src="./images/img2.png" alt="image 2" />
```

...and the CSS

```
#img1
{
z-index: 4;
position: relative;
top: 0%;
left: 5%;
opacity: 0;
padding: 20px;
}
#img2
{
z-index: 4;
width: 350px;
height: 140px;
position: relative;
top: 0%;
left: 15%;
opacity: 0;
padding: 20px;
}
```

...but it is not working.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you necessarily need JS? Can't you just add `class="hidden"` with `.hidden{ display:none; }`?

Comment: GIVE ALL THE IMAGES A PARTICULAR CLASS AND GIVE THE GIVE its css display:none property

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly I would try putting a JS alert in your (document).ready function to make sure that the code is being hit correctly (jQuery references, JS syntax are ok). Also, check via adding a watch in Mozilla Firebug (or other JS debugger) that JQuery is picking up the objects correctly ("img1", "img2").

You could also try just setting the style of img to display:none in the markup if it is always going to be hidden on page load every time.

I.e.,

```
<img src="imgs/image.jpg" style="display:none"></img>
```

the above logic could be moved to CSS.

Then just use your animate() function when they're required to show the images.

Comment: this answer actually made more sense, simpler (therefore faster loading and less buggy for weaker computers and crappy internet, important fact since i live in a country far, far away..) Thanks!

Comment: i think i said it first :) hmmm

Comment: Your first answer (pre its later edit) was one sentence and included the words "or something". So, no - not really first ;)

Answer (score 4):

Try to this one. `opacity: 0;` line delete.

http://jsfiddle.net/2wqwf/2/

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#img1").css({display, 'none'});
    $("#img2").css({display, 'none'});
});
```

Comment: This is (almost) identical to `hide()`

Answer (score 1):

Add a class to all images and set visible property hidden by default, and later on your animate function or something, remove that class. it will work

```
<style>
.hiddenclass
{
   display:none;
}
</style>

<img src="imgs/image1.jpg" class="hiddenclass"></img>

<img src="imgs/image2.jpg" class="hiddenclass"></img>

 ------

<img src="imgs/image3.jpg" class="hiddenclass"></img>
```

and in your animation script remove `hiddenclass` from all images by using `removeClass`

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `.html()` function

See Example: http://jsfiddle.net/ipsjolly/jLNKL/